# Is there a way to ask tfs what changesets were merge to form a changeset?

Tags: tfs, merge

I'd like to see what changesets were merged to create a changeset on a branch in the history.  This doesn't seem to be straight forward.  I've tried to use the Track Changeset functionality, but I can't seem to see anything useful.  I would also like it if I could do this from the command line so that I could potentially script a way to pull out appropriate changesets separately.

## Edit

Ok, seems that using Timeline Tracking, I can get the changesets from the Track Changes feature.  Now is there a way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Tracking Changeset** window  is the right way to  **[View where and when changesets have been merged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged)**.

For the overview and some meaning of the elements in tracking changeset window, you could refer above link. And switch to timeline view will make the result more directly,clearly.

Afraid you could not do this through command line. There is a [Merges Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merges-command), but could not specific a single changeset.

However, you could use TFS API to achieve this, take a look at below two similar questions:

- [Find changeset id parent of a branch in tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835798/find-changeset-id-parent-of-a-branch-in-tfs)
- [Is there a way to find out the source changeset from which a particular branch was created in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410110/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-source-changeset-from-which-a-particular-branch-w)

The answer contains a link to a [blog](http://netexp.blogspot.sg/2012/11/tfs-who-is-father-of-my-branch.html) post which contains many details, including TFS API and a custom command-line tool.